# New Elastic Beanstalk instance not using .htaccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I'm having a weird issue I've not encountered before: My new Elastic Beanstalk environment is not respecting my .htaccess files. It's odd because I don't recall this ever being a problem before. In fact I have an older EB environment that I set up years ago and it's fine with the game code.

This new environment is 64 bit Amazon Linux 2.

Looking elsewhere there are guides saying you need to edit your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file, but my EC2 instance doesn't have one. (I also don't have an `/etc/apache2` directory.) The closest it has is a `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` file.

I don't recall ever having to do this previously, and obviously I'm a bit concerned that my EC2 instance will forget any changes to any `.conf` files if I have to spawn new instances are created in the future.

How do you get my EB/EC2 instance to implement my .htaccess files?

Comment: "It's odd because I don't recall this ever being a problem before" - What versions of Apache are you using? On Apache 2.2 `.htaccess` files (or rather `.htaccess` _overrides_) are enabled by default; but on Apache 2.4 they are not and must be explicitly enabled _somewhere_ in the server config using the `AllowOverride` directive.

Comment: @MrWhite *facepalm* Amazon changed their latest EB package environments to use Nginx without mentioning it. Ugh. That might explain why .htaccess files weren't being respected anymore...! Doh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update to the other answer, you can now change the server in versions 3+ to apache by updating the proxy server in the configuration.

Answer (score 6):

From v3.0.0 onwards, Amazon changed their Elastic Beanstalk PHP Platforms to use **nginx** as their server instead of **Apache**. This is not mentioned anywhere when you're creating your platform, so it can catch you unawares.

If you want to use Apache, you need to select a platform version of v2.x.x.

See [the full history of Elastic Beanstalk PHP platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-php.html) for specific details.